# Android app internet issues

Tags: android, wifi

A few weeks ago I developped an Android app for my company. The app can be downloaded by our customers on the company's website.
It's an offline app, but the user needs to download all the datas at first use.
Me and my team went through a few tests on the office's wifi, with different devices (Samsung, Huawei, ...) running on different Android version (4.3 to 5.0)
At first use, the user logs in and a loading screen appears, saying that the datas for first use are being downloaded, and it could take time. However, this information is false as it only takes a few seconds

I have a lot of negative feedback from our customers saying that they are blocked at this "first use" loading screen. They can login but the download of the datas for the first use doesn't work. However, they were able to download the app easily, so their internet connection is working. Also, the login function also needs an internet connection, and it works.
I had one of the customer on the phone, I told him to reinstall the app. He did it a few times and it finally worked.
An other customer gave me his device after trying to reinstall the app a few times. I installed the app from my office and it worked perfectly.

It seems like the app doesn't work on some wifi.
I'm using Volley to make the request to download the datas, a message should be displayed if the device is not connected to the internet, but it doesn't show (it does if I stop the device's wifi). It seems like the app detects the network but has no internet connection, and only in a few cases (as it works in our office)

Could someone help me ?
What could possibly be wrong in my app ? How can I debug the situation ?

Comment: may be some proxy issue ?

Comment: how you are checking internet in available or not?

Comment: may the site which downloads the data is blocked on the user's wifi (Most offices allow only specific URLs to users).

Comment: It's a Firewall issue..  on some wifi if it's set on that.... Used the Exception for these issue in Thorws or try catch